# Unable to add site column to the list using code in SharePoint - 2010

Tags: 2010, site-column

I have a site column named "Temp".

I want to it to be added to the all lists available in site. To do so, I created a console application which contains the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://bipc11:1234/sites/demo"))
    {
        SPWebCollection webs = siteCollection.AllWebs;
        foreach (SPWeb site in webs)
        {
           foreach (SPList list in site.Lists)
           {
                AddFieldToList(list,site);
           }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void AddFieldToList(SPList list,SPWeb site)
{
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(@"http://bipc11:1234/sites/demo"))
    {
       using (SPWeb curSite = siteCollection.AllWebs[site.Name])
       {
           if(!list.Fields.ContainsField(Convert.ToString(curSite.AvailableFields["Temp"])))
                {
                    list.Fields.Add(curSite.AvailableFields["Temp"]);
                    list.Update();
                    Console.WriteLine("Field added to the list:{0}", list.Title);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code it finds the very first list which passes the condition, after that gives the error `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`.

How should I tackle this error? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify a collection you are iterating. You can use for loop to add the column to all lists following is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/demo"))
        {
            foreach (SPWeb web in siteCollection.AllWebs)
            {
                using (web)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < web.Lists.Count; i++)
                    {
                        SPList list = web.Lists[i];
                        AddFieldToList(list, web);
                    }
                }
            }                
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void AddFieldToList(SPList list, SPWeb site)
    {
        if (!list.Fields.ContainsField(Convert.ToString(site.AvailableFields["Temp"])))
        {
            list.Fields.Add(site.AvailableFields["Temp"]);
            list.Update();
            Console.WriteLine("Field added to the list:{0}", list.Title);
        }
    }
```

Also, you don't need to instantiate SPSite object in the AddFieldToList method

Answer (score 0):

As Nadeem Yousuf said you cannot modify a collection you are iterating. Also you have other mistakes.

First of all you don't need to open new context in AddFieldToList. Second, AvailableFields returns collection of the field, thus ContainsField should not work.

```
static void AddFieldToList(SPList list,SPWeb web)
{
    SPField field = web.Fields["Temp"];
    if(!list.Fields.ContainsField(field.Id)))
    {
          list.Fields.Add(field);
          list.Update();
          Console.WriteLine("Field added to the list:{0}", list.Title);
     }
};
```

Third, you should dispose webs in foreach

```
SPWebCollection webs = siteCollection.AllWebs;
foreach (SPWeb site in webs)
{
    ...

    if (site != null)
    {
        site.Dispose();
    }
}
```